# Default permission of hosts file

Tags: 11.04, permissions, hosts

I changed the permissions of my host file `/etc/hosts` by doing a `chmod og+w`.

What's the default permission so that I can switch it back?

Comment: Is it 444? Read all?

Comment: The reverse of that command is `sudo chmod og-w /etc/hosts`. Most files have permissions like `644` and directories `755`. Exceptions exists, highly sensitive files like `/etc/shadow` have `640`.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think the reverse applies for every command, may be just here but not in all situations and that's why I asked to be sure :)

Comment: The `sudo chmod o-w whatever` can almost always be executed without pain. Only shared directories like `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` have that permission bit set, having it in other directories might introduce a security hole.

Comment: Good point! I wasn't sure of the group part, may be it had the permission for the group and may be not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default file permissions for `/etc/hosts` is 644. (readable and writable for the owner, root, and readable for others.)

Comment: Just curious, why it needs to be executable for the owner?

Comment: It's not. 4 (read) + 2 (write) = 6. Read more on [file permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).

Comment: oh sry, yes that makes sense.